# How does sound propagate through a mesh structure?

Tags: experimental-physics, acoustics

I am assuming that the material and holes are approximately the same dimensions and also similar to the wavelength of the sound. In my case, around 2mm. How does varying those dimensions affect the transmission?

Comment: The mesh is going to diffract the sound [in a fairly obvious way](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mesh%20diffraction%20pattern). Were you after something more subtle than this?

Comment: @JohnRennie Not sure. There is often a difference between real world and theory. Besides, would longitudinal v transverse propagation make a difference?

Comment: No, sound diffracts by the same mechanism that light diffracts i.e. a path dependent phase difference.

Comment: Non linear effects? The mesh is not rigid